# Using wildcards in sed command

Tags: sed

The following command works as expected and changes the username to abc

```
sed -e 's/username=company_user/username=abc/' Service.properties
```

But if the username is something different other than 'company_user' it will fail for obvious reasons.
How do I use wildcards here?

Comment: What comes after the user name? Try `'s/username=.*/username=abc/'`.

Comment: If your sed is GNU sed, then you can read about sed [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) and [GNU extensions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is a valid username, but here's a start:

```
sed 's/username=[a-z0-9_]+/username=abc/i' Service.properties
```

This will replace any username consisting of upper or lower case letters (note the `i` at the end, which makes the pattern case-insensitive), numbers and/or underscores with "abc". If you need to add other characters, just add them within the `[]`.